# How to display a drop-down list of RDS instance snapshot ID's when creating a new stack from a template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudformation

I wrote a CloudFormation template which in addition to other stuff, also creates a RDS MySQL instance and restores data from a previously backed up DB instance snapshot.

I want to enable the user which is going to work with this template the option of selecting the rds instance snapshot ID from a drop-down menu.

I've seen that it's possible to select from a drop-down menu the VPC ID when using [Amazon's CloudFormation template which creates a Bastion host](https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/linux/bastion/latest/templates/linux-bastion.template) so I believe it is possible to do the same with the snapshot ID.

Example:
[image]

I was looking through Amazon's documentation, searching for the correct way to do that... I was thinking of doing something like:

```
"RDSSnapshotID" : {
  "Description" : "Choose the relevant snapshot",
  "Type" : { "Fn::RefAll" : "AWS::RDS::DBSnapshotIdentifier::Id" }
}
```

But I get an error when trying to load the template to CloudFormation:

> Template validation error: Template format error: Every Type member
>   must be a string.

Edit:

I now suspect that such a property ("AWS::RDS::DBSnapshotIdentifier::Id") doesn't exist.

Anyone knows if it can be done and how?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I found this [AWS documentation article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) which lists the available "AWS-Specific Parameter Types" and there isn't any parameter for RDS there so I guess this cannot be done.